# Out of memory killing mysql in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, nginx, fastcgi

I've been trying to optimize my Wordpress installation on a

- 12 core
- 32 GB RAM
- 320 GB SSD drive

with

- nginx
- varnish
- php5-fpm
- fastcgi
- APC (Page cache, Object Cache, Database Cache turned on with W3TC)

But every few days, I suddenly get a random `Out of memory` error and I assume sometimes it's mysql that's the top most process taking highest memory and it gets killed.

```
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568463] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568466] 273497 total pagecache pages
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568482] 0 pages in swap cache
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568485] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568487] Free swap  = 0kB
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568489] Total swap = 0kB
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568491] 8388507 pages RAM
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568493] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568495] 131593 pages reserved
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568497] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568515] [  417]     0   417     4868       75      13        0             0 upstart-udev-br
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568525] [  422]     0   422    12813      146      27        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568530] [  669]     0   669     3814       68      13        0             0 upstart-socket-
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568534] [  935]   102   935     9806       96      24        0             0 dbus-daemon
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568538] [  970]     0   970    10862       92      27        0             0 systemd-logind
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568542] [  981]   101   981    63960      320      28        0             0 rsyslogd
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568546] [ 1017]     0  1017     3818       62      13        0             0 upstart-file-br
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568549] [ 1046]     0  1046     3954       40      12        0             0 getty
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568553] [ 1050]     0  1050     3954       39      13        0             0 getty
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568556] [ 1059]     0  1059     3954       41      13        0             0 getty
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568560] [ 1060]     0  1060     3954       40      13        0             0 getty
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568563] [ 1063]     0  1063     3954       39      13        0             0 getty
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568567] [ 1087]     0  1087     4784       41      13        0             0 atd
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568571] [ 1088]     0  1088     5913       64      17        0             0 cron
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568575] [ 1094]     0  1094    15343      169      34        0         -1000 sshd
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568578] [ 1111]     0  1111     4797       67      14        0             0 irqbalance
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568582] [ 1112]     0  1112     1091       37       8        0             0 acpid
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568585] [ 1332]     0  1332    31675     1117      25        0             0 varnishd
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568589] [ 1423]     0  1423     3954       42      13        0             0 getty
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568613] [29802]     0 29802   329190     2709      69        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568618] [29957]     0 29957    33327      213      19        0             0 nginx
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568622] [29958]   107 29958    34193     1055      22        0             0 nginx
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568626] [29960]   107 29960    34187     1054      22        0             0 nginx
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568629] [29961]   107 29961    34191     1060      22        0             0 nginx
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568633] [29962]   107 29962    34183     1055      22        0             0 nginx
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568636] [29963]   107 29963    34203     1064      22        0             0 nginx
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568639] [29964]   107 29964    34197     1054      22        0             0 nginx
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568643] [29965]   107 29965    34186     1057      22        0             0 nginx
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568647] [29966]   107 29966    34217     1060      22        0             0 nginx
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568650] [29968]   107 29968    34188     1051      22        0             0 nginx
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568653] [29969]   107 29969    34192     1044      22        0             0 nginx
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568657] [29970]   107 29970    34232     1074      22        0             0 nginx
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568660] [29971]   107 29971    34181     1064      22        0             0 nginx
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568665] [ 5132]   107  5132   412513   163519     759        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568668] [ 5135]   107  5135   339206    97868     614        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568672] [ 5136]   107  5136   475254   230498     877        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568675] [ 5140]   107  5140   423646   189796     779        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568679] [ 5143]   107  5143   333504    89500     603        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568683] [ 5144]   107  5144   343835   106152     622        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568687] [ 5149]   107  5149   340029    96973     616        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568690] [ 5150]   107  5150   476366   241523     881        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568694] [ 5151]   107  5151   333534    93593     603        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568698] [ 5159]   107  5159   332573    19332     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568702] [ 5162]   107  5162   447723   222830     846        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568705] [ 5163]   107  5163   479445   232881     888        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568709] [ 5164]   107  5164   333406    96195     602        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568713] [ 5166]   107  5166   332701    17906     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568717] [ 5168]   107  5168   408535   169054     749        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568720] [ 5169]   107  5169   381918   155622     729        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568723] [ 5170]   107  5170   470959   252442     900        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568727] [ 5171]   107  5171   333469    93087     603        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568731] [ 5172]   107  5172   421632   176825     776        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568734] [ 5177]   107  5177   442051   206858     812        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568738] [ 5179]   107  5179   338434   101921     643        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568742] [ 5180]   107  5180   475146   235873     877        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568745] [ 5182]   107  5182   379270    71349     695        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568749] [ 5185]   107  5185   412482   158100     757        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568752] [ 5186]   107  5186   333355    94804     602        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568756] [ 5187]   107  5187   421562   175509     775        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568759] [ 5188]   107  5188   333532    89194     602        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568763] [ 5204]   107  5204   333404    90621     604        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568766] [ 5213]   107  5213   478340   236505     885        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568784] [ 5214]   107  5214   481792   242205     889        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568789] [ 5231]   107  5231   452303   214524     835        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568793] [ 5297]   107  5297   333534    89922     602        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568796] [ 5303]   107  5303   333213    23987     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568800] [ 5334]   107  5334   477066   241858     880        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568804] [ 5335]   107  5335   476600   232751     880        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568807] [ 5359]   107  5359   333508    94162     602        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568811] [ 5373]   107  5373   333251    90391     602        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568814] [ 5379]   107  5379   333404    90835     603        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568818] [ 5382]   107  5382   332766    27662     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568822] [ 5383]   107  5383   338905    97435     613        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568825] [ 5384]   107  5384   404036   173727     766        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568829] [ 5387]   107  5387   424555   180511     780        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568832] [ 5394]   107  5394   407296   148068     747        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568836] [ 5397]   107  5397   332830    44905     603        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568839] [ 5419]   107  5419   479561   241775     888        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568843] [ 5421]   107  5421   412473   163826     759        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568846] [ 5424]   107  5424   333473    86367     603        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568850] [ 5428]   107  5428   333231    53061     603        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568854] [ 5439]   107  5439   340035    93488     615        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568857] [ 5440]   107  5440   365213   124099     677        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568861] [ 5458]   107  5458   382191   153298     728        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568865] [ 5466]   107  5466   332834    30711     602        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568868] [ 5494]   107  5494   453111   221005     845        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568872] [ 5523]   107  5523   331981    40563     600        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568875] [ 5524]   107  5524   485030   247253     899        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568879] [ 5534]   107  5534   476151   238372     878        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568882] [ 5543]   107  5543   332766    17694     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568886] [ 5544]   107  5544   384262    78753     703        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568889] [ 5553]   107  5553   475644   231991     880        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568893] [ 5556]   107  5556   476172   231122     878        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568896] [ 5562]   107  5562   333410    90740     602        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568900] [ 5566]   107  5566   381982   152178     729        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568903] [ 5567]   107  5567   476851   239433     878        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568907] [ 5574]   107  5574   332828    29060     603        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568911] [ 5577]   107  5577   475659   229762     878        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568914] [ 5578]   107  5578   334187    18559     606        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568918] [ 5584]   107  5584   463990   226130     854        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568922] [ 5590]   107  5590   331708    20369     598        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568925] [ 5591]   107  5591   338304   106990     642        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568929] [ 5607]   107  5607   406258   146291     744        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568932] [ 5613]   107  5613   406521   141779     744        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568936] [ 5618]   107  5618   332552    22191     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568953] [ 5635]   107  5635   481591   237766     888        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568959] [ 5643]   107  5643   463363   219062     854        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568962] [ 5644]   107  5644   332894    37358     602        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568966] [ 5645]   107  5645   481660   234126     890        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568969] [ 5646]   107  5646   332714    30838     600        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568973] [ 5647]   107  5647   333227    27479     602        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568977] [ 5650]   107  5650   481910   234587     891        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568980] [ 5651]   107  5651   481208   233957     889        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568984] [ 5652]   107  5652   418425   122280     774        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568987] [ 5654]   107  5654   421513   174061     775        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568991] [ 5655]   107  5655   455417   210453     838        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568994] [ 5661]   107  5661   410233   167423     752        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.568998] [ 5693] 65534  5693   298523    54082     274        0             0 varnishd
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569002] [ 5801]   107  5801   332832    17860     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569006] [ 5802]   107  5802   332897    30380     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569009] [ 5803]   107  5803   341042    91666     618        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569013] [ 5804]   107  5804   475516   230789     878        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569016] [ 5806]   107  5806   334094    37059     605        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569020] [ 5807]   107  5807   440896   194812     810        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569023] [ 5808]   107  5808   332770    39507     600        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569027] [ 5809]   107  5809   332834    26562     602        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569030] [ 5810]     0  5810    26410      247      57        0             0 sshd
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569034] [ 5876]     0  5876     5670      530      16        0             0 bash
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569038] [ 5894]     0  5894     6272      168      18        0             0 top
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569041] [ 5900]   107  5900   333471    85670     602        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569045] [ 5901]   107  5901   333216    87048     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569048] [ 5902]   107  5902   333127    27248     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569052] [ 5903]   107  5903   402807   149681     760        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569056] [ 5904]   107  5904   475705   232271     880        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569059] [ 5905]   107  5905   332768    41900     600        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569063] [ 5906]   107  5906   332767    32583     599        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569066] [ 5907]   107  5907   332832    13166     593        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569070] [ 5908]   107  5908   393837   147178     720        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569073] [ 5909]   107  5909   481658   234291     890        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569077] [ 5910]   107  5910   476665   230149     880        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569081] [ 5911]   107  5911   332354    20848     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569084] [ 5912]   107  5912   332765    19477     600        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569088] [ 5914]   107  5914   398324   154057     761        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569091] [ 5915]   107  5915   463180   219728     854        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569095] [ 5916]     0  5916     1808       24       9        0             0 tail
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569098] [ 5917]     0  5917     1808       24       9        0             0 tail
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569102] [ 5918]     0  5918     1808       24       9        0             0 tail
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569105] [ 5942]   106  5942  2015476   114601     426        0             0 mysqld
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569123] [ 6092]     0  6092     6272      163      17        0             0 top
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569128] [ 6095]     0  6095     6272      164      17        0             0 top
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569132] [ 6096]     0  6096    12489      669      26        0             0 vi
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569135] [ 6103]     0  6103    12477      669      27        0             0 vi
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569139] [ 6220]   107  6220   333086    18326     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569142] [ 6230]   107  6230   332897    16288     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569146] [ 6237]   107  6237   405812   140589     743        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569149] [ 6238]   107  6238   407975   141948     747        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569153] [ 6240]   107  6240   333022    11540     484        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569157] [ 6246]   107  6246   330748    28319     595        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569160] [ 6251]   107  6251   330931    12602     594        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569164] [ 6252]   107  6252   361777    45794     658        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569167] [ 6261]   107  6261   332767    43184     600        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569171] [ 6262]   107  6262   332830    15915     600        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569174] [ 6263]   107  6263   332767    12677     581        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569178] [ 6264]   107  6264   454434   206515     835        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569182] [ 6268]   107  6268   412470   148178     759        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569185] [ 6275]   107  6275   332642    11005     486        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569189] [ 6277]     0  6277     6272      167      17        0             0 top
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569193] [ 6288]   107  6288   332958    30114     601        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569196] [ 6289]   107  6289   332766    14279     594        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569200] [ 6325]   107  6325   409376   143052     750        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569203] [ 6326]   107  6326   332573    10287     336        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569206] [ 6327]   107  6327   332830    12098     356        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569210] [ 6330]     0  6330     1808       24       9        0             0 tail
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569214] [ 6336]     0  6336     1808       23       9        0             0 tail
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569217] [ 6346]   107  6346   333084    10623     345        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569221] [ 6348]   107  6348   333022    10812     356        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569225] [ 6349]   107  6349   332830    16739     600        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569228] [ 6358]   107  6358   332704    10241     330        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569232] [ 6359]   107  6359   330810    10766     581        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569235] [ 6360]   107  6360   333086    10909     441        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569239] [ 6368]   107  6368   333022    10715     325        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569242] [ 6371]   107  6371   332766    10526     348        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569246] [ 6372]   107  6372   332830    17150     600        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569249] [ 6377]   107  6377   332363    15623     598        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569253] [ 6378]   107  6378   332701    10100     265        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569257] [ 6379]   107  6379   332958    10516     256        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569260] [ 6380]   107  6380   332766    10224     288        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569264] [ 6381]   107  6381   354800    34407     626        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569268] [ 6382]   107  6382   332637    10221     271        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569271] [ 6383]   107  6383   333086    10584     323        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569274] [ 6384]   107  6384   333163    10607     274        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569291] [ 6385]   107  6385   332765    13372     590        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569296] [ 6386]   107  6386   412391   145691     755        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569300] [ 6387]   107  6387   332701    10256     273        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569303] [ 6388]   107  6388   331132    14407     594        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569307] [ 6389]   107  6389   332766    10669     373        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569311] [ 6390]   107  6390   332830    10314     244        0             0 php5-fpm
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569314] Out of memory: Kill process 5170 (php5-fpm) score 30 or sacrifice child
May 20 04:11:14 my-server kernel: [86889.569439] Killed process 5170 (php5-fpm) total-vm:1883836kB, anon-rss:625456kB, file-rss:384312kB
May 20 04:11:57 my-server kernel: [86932.538067] init: php5-fpm main process (29802) killed by KILL signal
```

Is there something wrong in my php5-fpm/nginx settings? Please help.

Comment: try adding some swap memory.. what does `swapon -s` say?

Comment: `swapon -s` shows nothing. I don't have `swap` enabled.

Comment: I would suggest you to create 32 GB swap memory in that case. I actually had the same problem on a low end server and creating the swap resolved it. Having said all, 32GB is huge amount of RAM. Are you sure your script is well-optimized?

Comment: That's my actual concern. My website gets decent traffic (around 2000 to 3000 realtime traffic) and monthly runs into millions. Having said that, I might have messed up my settings somewhere because I'm assuming 32 GB should be enough. Or am I wrong? Also 32 GB swap memory for 32 GB RAM? Are you sure.

Comment: I followed this tutorial hosted @ Digital ocean  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: OP suggests to add same amount or swap as RAM.. Should not be a problem if you are not running out of space.. at max, the process will fail and swap file will  not  be created

Comment: What limit did you set in the number of children a php-fpm pool can create ? What kind of `pm` ? See [pm](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#pm) and the ones that follow. I see about 50 php-fpm processes that each takes real memory of more than 150MB. Those 50 processes already need 10GB or more. Try to estimate the max memory needed by a php-fpm process and check if the max_children * memory-needed fits in the 32GB minus memory needed by other services and kernel. If you have `pm = ondemand`, you cannot limit the max number of child process until one gets killed,...

Comment: After playing around with static, dynamic and ondemand (which many people suggested not to set as it's a high traffic site), these are my current settings: `pm = dynamic` ,  `pm.max_children = 300` , `pm.start_servers = 120` ,  `pm.min_spare_servers = 70`,  `pm.max_spare_servers = 120` ,  `pm.max_requests = 500`

Comment: So here we can see at least one problem : you have 50% of the fpm process that take more than 150MB of real memory (rss). If you multiply 300 processes by 150MB you have 45GB, which is a problem in 32GB of ram. Form your post I guess a max of 250MB per fpm process. 32GB / 250Mb = 128 processes. And nothing for MySQL, kernel and other services... Or make the calculation the order way : 32GB / 300 process = 100MB per process (and  nothing for MySQL and so on...). Reduce your `pm.max_children` to something that will fit in your machine or buy more ram (45GB + MySQL + ...)

Comment: Just see that your title mentions killing mysql but your posted log says killing php5-fpm. The principle is the same for MySQL with the number of connections or threads * memory per thread...